# Help with a linear transformation problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> This is my matrix $A$:
>   $$\begin{bmatrix}
> 1 & -3 & \hphantom{-}2 & \hphantom{-}5 & \hphantom{-}2 & \hphantom{-}0\\
> 0 & \hphantom{-}0  & \hphantom{-}1 & -2 & \hphantom{-}1 & \hphantom{-}1\\
> 0 & \hphantom{-}0  & \hphantom{-}0 & \hphantom{-}1 &  \hphantom{-}0 & \hphantom{-}0\\
> 0 & \hphantom{-}0  & \hphantom{-}0 & \hphantom{-}0 &  \hphantom{-}0 & \hphantom{-}0
> \end{bmatrix}$$
>
> **a.** Define the linear transformation $Tx = Ax$. Fill in the blanks  $$T: \mathbb{R}^{\Box} \to \mathbb{R}^{\Box}$$
>   with the dimensions of the domain and codomain.
>
> **b.** Is every vector $b$ in the codomain the image of a vector under $T$? Explain why or why not.

Im pretty lost on this homework problem. any help would be cool.

Comment: The boxes are clearer as "blanks" for this purpose than lines are, in my humble opinion. You're welcome to change it if you want.

Comment: nm yeah, your right

Answer (score 1):

For (a), do you know how matrix multiplication works? How many entries must the vector $x$ have? How many entries will $Ax$ have?

For (b), what do you know about the last entry of $Ax$ (regardless of $x$)?

Comment: A is a 4 x 6 matrix. im not sure what dimensions vector x is. but if vector x was  6 x 2 then a times x will be a 4 x 2 matrix. ax should have 8 entries then.

Comment: the last entry of a times x should be 0

Comment: A vector will be $n\times 1$ (an $n$-dimensional column vector) or $1\times n$ (an $n$-dimensional row vector), depending on which makes sense in context. Which works in this case (and what is $n$)?

Comment: Given that the last entry of $Ax$ is $0$, regardless of $x$, is the range equal to the whole codomain? If not, can you think of an easy example of a vector in the codomain that *isn't* in the range?